# React icons are not resolved

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, resolve, react-icons

Failed to compile.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ai' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'
ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.jsx 5:0-57
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ai' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.jsx 6:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/io' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.jsx 7:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ri' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.jsx 8:0-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/fa' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 6:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/io' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 7:0-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/fa' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 8:0-56
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/hi' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 9:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ti' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 10:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ci' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 12:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/pi' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 13:0-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/md' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 14:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lu' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 16:0-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/fi' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 17:0-72
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/io5' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 19:0-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Body.jsx' in 'C:\Users\janan\OneDrive\Desktop\dukaan\nishyan\src\components'

webpack compiled with 15 errors
```

I gave all these commands but still I receive these errors idk
`install npm i react-icons`

```
npm install
npm update
npm install @react-icons/all-files --save
npm install react-icons --save
```

any one please help me how to correct this error. this happens every time ..

Comment: Kindly add the react version you're using.

Comment: i use react 18. 2.0 and node 18.18.1

Comment: You should tell us what bundler (or something like a bundler) are you using

Comment: React application using Create React App (CRA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all there is no need to install `@react-icons/all-files` package
just run the command

```
npm install react-icons --save // if using npm
yarn add react-icons // if using yarn
```

then you can simply use like following

```
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Example = () =>  {
    return <h2> fa bear <FaBeer /> </h2>
}
```

if it doesn't work then try to delete and reinstall node_modules

happy coding :)

Comment: i used these commands... but it didnt work . Remove-Item -Recurse -Force node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install

Comment: do check if you have permissions to allow editing of files and folders in the C drive.
Also try deleting the node modules directly using file manager instead of using cmd line.

Comment: I am still trying why the icons are showing but  Thank you everyone for your kind replies.